# Dynamically Insert New Table Row After Last Cell In Row

Tags: php

I have seen some examples here, but none of them are really doing what I want. I can have up to 100 rows according to bale numbers in the database that I am pulling from. I have the backend working and all, but the problem is the rows just span across horizontally when I want them to show as new rows for each bale number (the new row starts after each exit weight). What's the best/correct way to go about this? I am trying to do all this logic using PHP. If I just wrap the td tags in my PHP for each with tr tags, then I just get the a long vertical display of data... I'm stuck. Thanks!

[image]

You can see the html, my JS and PHP are (separate files):

HTML

```
<table id="table" align="center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Bale #</th>
                    <th>Cable #</th>
                    <th>Shipping #</th>
                    <th>GP Cable Type</th>
                    <th>Exit Weight</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="bale_data">
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

JS

```
function baleData() {
 $.ajax({
    url: './php/baleData.php',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#bale_data').append(data);
    },
    error: function(xrs, thrownError, xhr) {
        alert("Ajax Error" + xrs.status + thrownError + xhr.status);
    }
});
};
```

PHP

```
//Create array
$column = array("bale_no","cable_no","shipment_no","gp_cable_type","exit_weight");

//Define JSON array
$array = array();

//Run SQL for each array value
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
    foreach ($column as $value) {
        $sql="SELECT $value FROM bundle_lanes WHERE bale_no='$i'";

        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error'.mysql_error());

        while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            print "<td><input value=\"".$data[$value]."\"></td>";
        }
    }
}

//Return array
print json_encode($array);
```

Comment: `WHERE bale_no='$i'` is for all columns you mentioned in the `array("bale_no","cable_no","shipment_no","gp_cable_type","exit_weight")` ??

Comment: the array is for each SELECT statement to return values for each column in the database according to the bale_no "$i" which can be up to 100, which is why I made that for loop. and the for each just iterates through the column array to return every value in that array (existing in the SQL database) corresponding to each bale_no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making more calls than you really need, and you're not creating a new row anywhere. This will be only 1 query per $i, though you can lessen that as well by limiting your query to just 100.

```
$column = array("bale_no","cable_no","shipment_no","gp_cable_type","exit_weight");

//Define JSON array
$array = array();

//Run SQL for each array value
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
        $sql="SELECT ".implode(',',$column)." FROM bundle_lanes WHERE bale_no='$i'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error'.mysql_error());
        while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            print "<tr>";
            foreach($column as $value)
                print "<td><input value=\"".$data[$value]."\"></td>";
            print "</tr>";
        }
}
```

If you want to get rid of that foreach, change your query to

```
$sql="SELECT ".implode(',',$column)." FROM bundle_lanes LIMIT 100";
```

Comment: Wow you're awesome man, thanks!! I believe I only want one query per, because there should only be one bale number..

Answer (score 1):

On this part of the code:

```
print "<td><input value=\"".$data[$value]."\"></td>";
```

You are creating just the table data portion of your table. You need to create a row `tr` per result of your SQL, and append several `td` for each of the objects data.

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  print "<tr>";
  print "<td><input value=\"".$result[$attribute1]."\"></td>";
  print "<td><input value=\"".$result[$attribute2]."\"></td>";
  print "<td><input value=\"".$result[$attribute3]."\"></td>";
  // etc...
  print "</tr>";
}
```

P.S.: The above code is an example of how you should do it. You must adapt it to your context.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 5 collumns, you can add a counter that counts each cell you add and after each 5 cells reset the counter and create a new line.
Here's an example:

```
$counter = 0;

//Run SQL for each array value
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
        foreach ($column as $value) {
                if($counter == 0){
                print "<tr>"; //Create the new row
            }
                $sql="SELECT $value FROM bundle_lanes WHERE bale_no='$i'";

                    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error'.mysql_error());

                while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                print "<td><input value=\"".$data[$value]."\"></td>";
                $counter++; //After we added a new cell we update the counter
                }
            if($counter == 5){ //After each 5 added cells we end the new row and reset the counter
                print "</tr>";
                $counter = 0;
            }
        }
}
```